# Access remote Oracle database with Powershell

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, database-connection, nuget-package

I need to be able to connect to an Windows 7 based Oracle server (32 bit, Oracle XE) which is on my network. The machine I need to connect from is running Windows 7 64 bit, with Powershell installed on both machines.

I have installed the Oracle 32 bit client on my 64 bit machine and have SQL Developer installed on both machines. I want to create a script that connects the the Oracle database and runs a simple SELECT query. I can't get it to connect though.

I have tried using ODAC (I think I have to install Visual Studio to use this as the install fails). I hear that OleBD might be a lot easier. I would like to do it with TNS is possible. Can anyone offer me any guidance here? I have a book on Powershell and Oracle and I am still confused, I can't get past the first stage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/04/use-oracle-odp-net-and-powershell-to-simplify-data-access.aspx) help?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a small example of what I was using in 2015.

```
# Ora002.ps1
# Need installation of ODAC1120320Xcopy_x64.zip 
# The 32 bit version also exists

# Load the good assembly
Add-Type -Path "C:\oracle\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"

# Connexion string
$compConStr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.213.5.123)(PORT=1609)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=COMPEIERE)));User Id=TheLogin;Password=ThePassword;"

# Connexion
$oraConn= New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($compConStr)
$oraConn.Open()

# Requête SQL
$sql1 = @"
SELECT XX_MYSESSION_ID FROM XX_SILOGIXWSLOG 
  WHERE xx_name='customer_log'
  AND xx_param_4 IS NOT NULL
"@

$command1 = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql1,$oraConn)

# Execution
$reader1=$command1.ExecuteReader()

$n = 0
while ($reader1.read())
{
  $reader1["XX_MYSESSION_ID"]  
}

# Fermeture de la conexion
$reader1.Close()
$oraConn.Close()

Write-Output $retObj
```

**----- Edited in fall 2017 -----**

For a while now Oracle edited a full managed DLL for .NET which is available through Nugets :

```
# Download the package if it's not on the disk    
$version = '12.2.1100'
try
{
  if (! $(Test-Path ".\NugetPackages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.$version\lib\net40\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"))
  {
    $ManagedDataAccess = Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess -Destination ".\NugetPackages" -Force -Source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2' -ProviderName NuGet -RequiredVersion $version -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  }
  Add-Type -Path ".\NugetPackages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.$version\lib\net40\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException]
{
  $global:OracleError = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{"StackTrace"=$_.ScriptStackTrace;"Detail" = "Ligne $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber) : $($_.exception.message)";"TimeStamp"=([datetime]::Now)}
  $log = $null
}

# Connexion
$oraConn= New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection (($compConStr)
$oraConn.Open()

# Requête SQL
$sql1 = @"
SELECT XX_MYSESSION_ID FROM XX_SILOGIXWSLOG 
  WHERE xx_name='customer_log'
  AND xx_param_4 IS NOT NULL
"@

$command1 = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql1,$oraConn)

# Execution
$reader1=$command1.ExecuteReader()

$n = 0
while ($reader1.read())
{
  $reader1["XX_MYSESSION_ID"]  
}

# Fermeture de la conexion
$reader1.Close()
$oraConn.Close()

Write-Output $retObj
```

Comment: I will have a go with this. To install ODAC1120320Xcopy_x64 - do you need to install Visual Studio for this or any .net framework components?

Comment: Just unzip the Odac file and follow the readme.htm file to install "ODP.NET4 - Oracle Data Provider for .NET 4".

Comment: I have tried to do this. When I run install.bat a command prompt window briefly appears then disappears and nothing else happens. I already have Oracle client (32 bit) installed. Will this be causing problems do you think?

Comment: I really don't know, are you sure to have .net framework installed on this machine ?

Answer (score 3):

I have Updated the Above code with the Oracle DLL path.
While we connect with Oracle from Powershell We connect to Managed Oracle service DLL, which can be found on the path Mentioned below.

May be I could be wrong but the below code worked for me.

```
cls
# Ora002.ps1
# Need installation of ODAC1120320Xcopy_x64.zip 
# The 32 bit version also exists

# Load the good assembly
Add-Type -Path "C:\app\ssz\product\12.1.0\client_1\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"

# Production connexion string
$compConStr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=*<Valid Host>*)(PORT=*<Valid Port>*)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=*<SErviceNameofDB>*)));User Id=*<User Id>*;Password=*<Password>*;"

# Connexion
$oraConn= New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($compConStr)
$oraConn.Open()

# Requête SQL
$sql1 = @"SELECT col FROM tbl1 
WHERE col1='test'
"@

$command1 = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql1,$oraConn)

# Execution
$reader1=$command1.ExecuteReader()

while ($reader1.read())
{
  $reader1["col"]  
}

# Fermeture de la conexion
$reader1.Close()
$oraConn.Close()

Write-Output $retObj
```

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer has a dependency to do client install and it's also outdated as Oracle has released a new managed version. You can use [.NET Oracle library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) DLL, just make sure you have the required DLL file under the lib folder.

```
Add-Type -Path "lib\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"

$query = "select  1 as Col1, 2 as Col2, 3 as Col3 from dual
          union
          select  4 as Col1, 5 as Col2, 6 as Col3 from dual
          union
          select  7 as Col1, 8 as Col2, 9 as Col3 from dual"

$cn   = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection -ArgumentList "TNS-ConnectionString-Here"
$cmd  = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand    -ArgumentList $query

$cmd.Connection = $cn

try {
    $cn.Open()

    $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

    while ($reader.Read()) {
        $col1 = $reader["Col1"]
        $col2 = $reader["Col2"]
        $col3 = $reader["Col3"]

        Write-Host $col1, $col2, $col3
    }

    $reader.Dispose()

} catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
} finally {
    $cmd.Dispose()
    $cn.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Right, that'is the on I use now, but it just not exists two years ago.